# Error: Aborted at 1556435360 (unix time) try "date -d @1556435360" if you are using GNU date #6760

Tags: centos, caffe

When I tried to install Caffe, everything was good after the following steps:

```
make clean
make -j32
make test -j32
```

However, when I tried:

```
make runtest -j32
```

I met the following problem:

```
*** Aborted at 1556439150 (unix time) try "date -d @1556439150" if you are using GNU date *** PC: @     0x7fa260b2f87d H5C_protect
*** SIGSEGV (@0x60) received by PID 100029 (TID 0x7fa1e17fe700) from PID 96; stack trace: ***
    @     0x7fa244fbc6d0 (unknown)
    @     0x7fa260b2f87d H5C_protect
    @     0x7fa260b14690 H5AC_protect
    @     0x7fa260be9047 H5O_protect
    @     0x7fa260c108ef H5O_msg_exists
    @     0x7fa260ba144f H5G_open
    @     0x7fa260ba18fa H5G__open_name
    @     0x7fa260ba1ec2 H5G_iterate
    @     0x7fa260bdc7a3 H5Literate
    @     0x7fa245892c47 caffe::hdf5_load_nd_dataset_helper<>()
    @     0x7fa245891369 caffe::hdf5_load_nd_dataset<>()
    @     0x7fa2459bedf4 caffe::HDF5DataLayer<>::LoadHDF5FileData()
    @     0x7fa2459bdbf8 caffe::HDF5DataLayer<>::LayerSetUp()
    @     0x7fa2458ab3dc caffe::Net<>::Init()
    @     0x7fa2458ad032 caffe::Net<>::Net()
    @     0x7fa2459fa496 caffe::Solver<>::InitTrainNet()
    @     0x7fa2459fb4f3 caffe::Solver<>::Init()
    @     0x7fa2459fb7cf caffe::Solver<>::Solver()
    @     0x7fa2459f1df4 caffe::Creator_RMSPropSolver<>()
    @     0x7fa2458b432e caffe::SolverRegistry<>::CreateSolver()
    @     0x7fa2458b4e3c caffe::Worker<>::InternalThreadEntry()
    @     0x7fa2458ce250 caffe::InternalThread::entry()
    @     0x7fa2458ceb86 boost::detail::thread_data<>::run()
    @     0x7fa25fdbb24a (unknown)
    @     0x7fa244fb4e25 start_thread
    @     0x7fa244cdebad __clone make: *** [runtest] Segmentation fault
```

Screenshot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFlGu.jpg)

Can anyone tell me how to fix it?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of my colleagues, I found that the problem was that I called multithreading. Therefore, removing "*-j32*" and simply running "*make runtest*" will solve the problem.